# Extract Repeated Substrings from a List or Body of Text

Tags: nlp, text-extraction

Yes - This question has been asked in variations over the years but it seems a number of variables impact the best approach based on use case.

We have a database of webpage titles - many of which contain repeated strings - such as the website's name or website's section or both.  We are trying to extract the most repeated phrases to create a dictionary that will allow us to remove the substrings in a separate process.

The analysis will typically be against 10,000 lines of text with a max length of 256 characters. We also expect the substrings to be delimited by special characters such as "-", "|" or ":"

Solutions we have seen include regex, suffix arrays and suffix trees but we are unsure which would be the most efficient given our data structure. This calculation needs to be done thousands of times per day against unique lists.

Here is an example of a list:

```
Sports lottery sales soar 70% in June on FIFA World Cup | Society | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Scorching heat forecast to continue Tuesday | Society | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Tech startups eye Taiwan's market | video | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Taiwan headline news | Society | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
About 30% of working fathers feel alienated from children: poll | Society | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News
Taiwan wins 2 championships in Pony League baseball world series | Entertainment & Sports | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News
A smart way to escape in a fire | video | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Taiwan headline news | What the Papers Say | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Taiwanese co-authors article nominated by European publisher | Society | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Taiwan to help Indonesia with post-earthquake relief: MOFA | Politics | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS
Taiwan shares close down 0.37% | Economics | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News
Taiwan shares open higher | Economics | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News
U.S. dollar closes lower on Taipei forex market | Economics | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News
```

From this list we would want to receive back the data including any punctuation or delimiters:

```
| FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS = 8 Occurrences
| FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News = 5 Occurrences 
| Society | FOCUS TAIWAN - CNA ENGLISH NEWS = 4 Occurrences 
| Economics | FocusTaiwan Mobile - CNA English News = 3 Occurrences
```

and so on...Any suggestions on the most appropriate approach to investigate would be very welcome.

*sample analysis data extracted from https://www.online-utility.org/text/analyzer.jsp